# Creating object inside loop

Tags: java

I am making a texted based game and I have problem creating objects inside a loop

here is my code

```
int i = 1;
        Skill[] Skill_List = null;
        String[] Skill_Info;
        File directory = new File("D:\Program Files\Game_dev2\src\Database\Skills");
        int FileCount = directory.list().length;
        while (i < FileCount - 1) {
            Scanner Skill_Info_Data = new Scanner(
                    new File("D:\Program Files\Game_dev2\src\Database\Skills\Skill" + (i) + ".csv"));
            int j = 0;
            while (Skill_Info_Data.hasNext()) {
                Skill_Info = Skill_Info_Data.nextLine().split(",");
                String Name = Skill_Info[0];
                String Type = Skill_Info[1];
                String Desc = Skill_Info[2];
                int Skill_Level = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[3]);
                int Effect = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[4]);
                int Effect2 = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[5]);
                int Manacost = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[6]);
                int Cooldown = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[7]);
                String Skill_From = Skill_Info[8];
                int Power_Gain = Integer.parseInt(Skill_Info[9]);

                Skill_List = new Skill[] { new Skill(Name, Type, Desc, Skill_Level, Effect, Effect2, Manacost, Cooldown,
                        Skill_From, Power_Gain) };
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

The problem is that the there is only 1 skilled stored in the array and I am running out of idea on how to fix this.

Comment: Because you only ever assign a single element array to that variable. If you want to add things, use a list instead, and add to it.

Comment: This is probably too broad for this site, as it has to do with pretty basic stuff that would be best served with a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is here:

```
Skill_List = new Skill[] { new Skill(Name, Type, Desc, Skill_Level, Effect, Effect2, Manacost, Cooldown, Skill_From, Power_Gain) };
```

You overwrite the old `Skill_List` variable each time so you only ever have 1 item. You could do this:

```
Skill_List[j] = new Skill(Name, Type, Desc, Skill_Level, Effect, Effect2, Manacost, Cooldown, Skill_From, Power_Gain);
```

But before you can do that, you need to know ahead of time how many items the array will hold, and create the array with that amount. So you would change

```
Skill[] Skill_List = null;
```

to

```
Skill[] Skill_List = new Skill[10];
```

But this limits you to 10 skills. The better option is to use a `List`. These containers can hold a variable amount of data.

```
ArrayList<Skill> Skill_List = new ArrayList<Skill>();  // Create empty list
//...
Skill_List.add(new Skill(Name, Type, Desc, Skill_Level, Effect, Effect2, Manacost, Cooldown, Skill_From, Power_Gain));
```

Each time you call `add` the list grows by 1. If you really want an array, you can call the `toArray()` function after you've built the list.